# Calculate vertical lines intersection hexagon at regular interval

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to calculate the total size of vertical lines that dissect an hexagon regular, like the one on the image.

[image]

I would like to know the internal size of the blue lines inside the hexagon, these lines have a separation of the size of 'h', and they start from the left point of the hexagon. All the faces of the hexagon are the same, and this size is 'd'. Also the hexagon is always with his horizontal size down.

What I have tried is to divide the hexagon in 2 triangles and a rectangle as the image 2 shows.

[image]

Then calculate the height and the base of the isosceles triangle 1, with the length of 'd' and the angle 120, to know how many vertical lines of width 'h' can fit in there. Then I use the formula of arithmetic progression to generate the total size of the vertical lines as $numberOfLines * ((sizeOfFirstLine + sizeOfLastLine) / 2)$. Then I do the same for the another triangle.

Then for the rectangle, I simply multiply 'h' by the number of lines that fit inside the rectangle.

The result of this operation gives me a wrong answer (I have calculated manually these lines to compare).

Its there any other way to solve this? Is the use of an Arithmetic progression good for this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach is a good one.  Using the arithmetic progression is correct for the side triangles.  It would be helpful to show an example of where it is wrong, otherwise I am guessing.  One problem would be if there is one less line in region 2 than you expect because the leftmost is moved too far right by the leftover of region 1.